# Expressing an equation in matrix form

Tags: matrices

$ x +2y + z - 4 = 0 \\ 3x - 4y - 2z - 2 = 0\\ 5x + 3y +5z +1 = 0$

I am trying to express the above equations in matrix form Ax=b. I can normally do this, but since there are three equations which have four elements in the main part, I am not sure how to do this.

My first thought was to do this:

$
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 1 & -4\\3 & -4 & -2 & -2\\5 & 3 & 5 & 1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\\1\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}
$

I am not sure what to do with the numbers without an assigned variable. I intend to use the Ax=b matrix to solve it using the inverse and then Guassian elimination methods.

Is the above expression valid in representing the equations in a matrix? Any help in expressing the equations in the correct matrix would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See the following link for more-http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/Alg/AugmentedMatrix.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you should set it up as

$
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 1 \\3 & -4 & -2 \\5 & 3 & 5 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}4\\2\\-1\end{bmatrix}
$

This gives you a square matrix which is (probably) invertible.  Then multiply both sides of the equation on the left by the inverse.

Comment: Thank you for the help, that makes a lot more sense now. Just another quick question, why do the signs of the elements in the far right matrix invert?

Comment: If you start with the original system of equation, you move the constants to the other side of the equation by subtracting them from both sides.  This introduces the sign.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this so clearly. I am still new to matrix algebra.

Comment: You're welcome.  Soon enough, you'll move from thinking about linear equations to just thinking about matrix equations, and then you'll move from thinking about matrices to thinking about linear transformations, and you won't even remember having confusion at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Pull the "unassigned" numbers to the RHS, they form the inhomogenity $b=(4,2,-1)^t$.